# How can I validate from a list with the "pattern" attribute without creating directives?

Tags: angularjs, validation

A city input field displays a suggested list of options from existing cities as the user inputs their city.  I'd like to validate the user's input prior to submitting the form to ensure the city is one of the cities in the list.

Without over-complicating things with directives, I'm wondering if I can do it in the "pattern" attribute?

This fails the pattern regex validation because it returns true/false

```
{{cities.includes(registerForm.city.$viewValue)}}
```

Is there some sort of "if" statement I can run instead so that if the city is one from the list, the view value is returned as the regex expression and thus passes the check?

```
<input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" id="city"
       ng-model="selected" autocomplete="off"
       typeahead="city for city in cities| filter:$viewValue" required
       pattern="{{if(cities.includes(registerForm.city.$viewValue)) return registerForm.city.$viewValue;}}">

<div ng-messages="registerForm.city.$error">
    <p ng-message="pattern">Invalid city</p>
</div>
```

Comment: AngularJS Expressions accept [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), not `if` statements.

Comment: Why are you not using drop-down which will have the cities in your list and let user select the city from the drop-down?

Comment: @Harshad, I'd rather the user type in their city as opposed to try and look through a list.  I know I find them annoying.

Comment: May be, for this you can also make use of auto complete dropdowns. This way, you can type and select cities from your list only. Take a look, hope it helps. https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.7/api/directive/mdAutocomplete

Comment: @georgeawg thank you!  This is what I was looking for.